# Calendário em JS e em HTML

Tags: javascript

O meu objetivo é através do código abaixo, criar um calendário atua, mas está-me a dar erro e não estou a conseguir criar bem a tabela, pois exceto o que já tenho em HTML, não aparece mais nada.

```html
<html lang="pt">
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    window.onload=function(){
    Calendario();
    function Calendario(){
      // Saber qual a data atual e guardar numa variavel o dia, mês, ano e em que dia da semana vamos
      var data_atual = new Date();
      var mês = data_atual.getMonth();
      var dia = data_atual.getDate();
      var ano = data_atual.getFullYear();
      var dia_semana = data_atual.getDay();

      // Quardar em lista o total de dias de cada mês, o nome dos dias da semana e o nome dos mêses
      var dias_fev="";
      var total_dias=[31,dias_fev,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
      var meses=["Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Maio","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"];

      //Determina se o mês de Fevereiro tem 28 ou 29 dias
      if (ano%4==0){
        if ((ano%100==0) && (ano%400!=0)){
          dias_fev=29;
        }
        else{
          dias_fev= 28;
        }
      }

      //Identificar o mês
      document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = meses[mês+1];

      //Criar a tabela
      var tabela = document.getElementById("tabela_calend");
      var linha1 = tabela.insertRow(1);

      //Irá criar todos os dias que já passaram até agora
      var dias_passados=dia-1; //guarda os dias que já passaram desse mês
      while (dias_passados>0){
        var i=0; //o i corresponde a cada linha que será criada a cada 7 dias (1 semana -> 7 dias)
        var linha = tabela.insertRow(i);
        var seg = linha.insertCell(0);
        var ter = linha.insertCell(1);
        var qua = linha.insertCell(2);
        var qui = linha.insertCell(3);
        var sex = linha.insertCell(4);
        var sab = linha.insertCell(5);
        var dom = linha.insertCell(6);
        for (i==1; i<8; i++){
          if (dia_semana==i){
            tabela.rows[0].cells[i-1].innerHTML==dia;
          }
        }
        for(i=1; i<8; i++){
          if(tabela.rows[0].cells[i-1].value==""){
            dias_passados-=i;
          }
         }
         dias_passados=-1;
     }

     //Enqunto o dia for menor que o total de dias do mes respetivo, ele ira criar celulas e adicionar os dias
      var dias_futuros=dia+1;
      
     while (dias_futuros<total_dias[mês+1]){
        var i=1; //o i corresponde a cada linha que será criada a cada 7 dias (1 semana -> 7 dias)
        var linha = tabela.insertRow(i);
        var seg = linha.insertCell(0);
        var ter = linha.insertCell(1);
        var qua = linha.insertCell(2);
        var qui = linha.insertCell(3);
        var sex = linha.insertCell(4);
        var sab = linha.insertCell(5);
        var dom = linha.insertCell(6);
        for (i==1; i<8; i++){
          if (dia_semana==i){
            tabela.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML==dia;
          }
        }
        for(i=1; i<8; i++){
          if(tabela.rows[1].cells[i].value==""){
            dias_futuros+=i;
          }
         }
         i+=7;
         dias_futuros++;
       }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="fundo">
    <div><h1 id="mes"></h2></div>
    <table id="tabela_calend">
      <tr>
        <td><h3>Segunda</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Terça</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Quarta</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Quinta</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Sexta</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Sábado</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Domingo</h3></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você tem muitos erros de digitação no código, e o primeiro erro que lhe aparece de "Unexpected end of input" é `{` ou `}` a mais ou a menos. No seu caso está pelo menos um `}` faltando, o que fecha o `window.onload`. Agora isto é sinal que você está a tentar escrever o código todo até ao fim e testar depois. Essa não é a forma correta, você deve fazer bloco a bloco aos poucos e ir confirmando que está a sair como quer para ser facil de corrigir qualquer problema que surja. Ainda assim tem vários outros erros pequenos como este `for (i==1; `

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver passo a passo!